# TanStack Svelte Table Pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, svelte, tanstack

I was using TanStack Table Svelte Library and I wanted to use pagination but they haven't given any example on that, if anyone has any idea how to use the pagination on the Svelte table or if there are any methods that can help?

Answer (score 1):

Using basic example found at https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/examples/svelte/basic as a starting point, make the following changes to enable basic pagination:

```
<script>
import {
  ...
  getPaginationRowModel, // Import the pagination model
} from '@tanstack/svelte-table';

...

const options = writable({
  ...
  getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(), // Enable pagination
  autoResetPageIndex: true, // Automatically update pagination when data or page size changes
});

let pageSize = 10; // number of rows to show
$table.setPageSize(pageSize);

</script>




<table>
<!-- No need to edit table code/html - the rows shown/hidden will be handled by svelte-table  -->
</table>




<!-- Add buttons to control page index -->
<button
    on:click{() => $table.previousPage()}
    disabled={!$table.getCanPreviousPage()}
>
  Prev
</button>

<button
    on:click{() => $table.nextPage()}
    disabled={!$table.getCanNextPage()}
>
  Next
</button>
```

Comment: Does tanstack table for Svelte or in general does it support firebase pageTokens @Jesse Reilly

Comment: @Gaurav Unsure - I haven't used Firebase before.